# Network router dropping connection and causing a change in SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Linksys E1200 that is proving to be problematic for wireless connections. At times, the connection will just drop out and my computer will automatically reconnect to the network (called NetworkName). However, the computer (running Windows 8 or 10) will sometimes require me to connect to another network (called NetworkName 2) which is the only network with the same wireless strength. This issue occurs with other laptop devices that run Windows 8 or 10 as well. For mobile devices (Apple and Samsung), the signal does drop/lag but the SSID remains the same. I'm curious if the dropping out and SSID change is indicative of a problem with the router.

I checked the properties for both NetworkName and NetworkName 2. They have the same

- Connection-specific DNS suffix
- IPv6 address
- Temporary IPv6 address
- Link-local IPv6 address
- IPv4 address
- Subnet Mask
- Default Gateway

Fixes that I have tried (in multiple combinations) include

- Changing channel
- Power cycle (which fixes the problem for a short time but the issue will resurface)
- Changing wireless encryption methods
- Making sure that not all IP addresses are reserved/taken
- Router firmware is up to date

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your wireless router dual band? NetworkName could be the 2.4 GHz band and NetworkName 2 could be the 5 GHz band.

Comment: I believe it only has the 2.4 gHz band, as far as the specs on linksys' website goes

Comment: The network name being shown by Windows may change if Windows sees some change in the connection, so it's definitely not the SSID that changes, it is just the name Windows gives to the connection (by adding a increasing number after the original name).

Comment: @zagrimsan: what kind of changes usually warrant the appended number?

Comment: I don't really know, and after quick googling it seems usually people only want to get rid of the "extra" without caring about the reason they originally appeared. Your case is rather odd, though, since unless you (or somebody else) change any setting related to the network or the wireless AP, there shouldn't be any reason for anything related to the connection to change. DrZoo's guess is about the only one I can come up with, either. I wanted just to emphasise and clarify that the SSID isn't changing (Windows can't change that).

Comment: What you could do to verify if there is anything (relevant) changing in the wifi connection/AP settings is to run `netsh wlan show all` when the connection shows as "SSID" and when it shows as "SSID 2", and then compare those. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2011/08/02/tip-42-viewing-detailed-windows-7-wireless-information/) for more details on the output of that command.